# Find position of stage relative to screen?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to make a ball that bounces when the SWF window moves in Flash AS3. Is it possible to find the position of the stage relative to the monitor/screen?

For example, having the SWF window at the top-left of the screen would say `X:0, Y:0`, and at the bottom right something like `X:1000, Y:800`.

Comment: It is possible if using AIR,   are you using AIR?

Comment: No I'm not. Do I need to?

Comment: Yes, I don't think you can do so with just a Flash Projector.

Comment: @Zoweb Where are you expecting this to work? In a browser? In your desktop?

Comment: It would be on desktop.

Answer (score 1):

When using AIR, you get access to the [NativeWindow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html).

As you can see on the documentation,  the native window object has `width`, `height`, `x` and `y` properties as well as a `bounds` property.  These can be used to determine where the window is in relation to the entire desktop.

```
trace(stage.nativeWindow.bounds);
```

Comment: OK, I'm not used to AIR. When I try that in AIR (Desktop), nothing happens? No window opens, nothing is traced?

Comment: You should always have a window when using air.  What is your IDE?  FlashPro/Adobe Animate?   FlashDevelop?    Most likely you just don't have everything configured for air.

Comment: I'm using Flash Proffesional CC 2015, and I don't know if everything is configured properly because I havn't used Air before..